# Help needed in passing arguments from command line in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

```
#function myfunc
myfunc(){
echo $1
case $1 in

    e)
            a=5
            ;;
    q)
            a=10
            ;;

esac
}

myfunc
```

I need help in following :

```
$myfunc.sh e
```

`echo $1` is not showing anything. `case` is also not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is, inside the function $1, $2, ... are function arguments not the script arguments, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966048/access-arguments-to-bash-script-inside-a-function

Comment: To follow up on Jason's comment, the solution is `myfunc "$@"`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass at least one parameter to the `myfunc` function when you call it. So, your `myfunc.sh` script should look like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#function myfunc
myfunc(){
    echo $1
    case $1 in
        e) a=5 ;;
        q) a=10 ;;
        *) a='not e or q' ;;
    esac
    echo $a
}

myfunc $1   #in this case you can also use $@ or $*
```

More about:

- [How to read command line arguments in a bash script](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_read_command_line_arguments_in_a_bash_script)
- [Passing parameters to a bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212219/passing-parameters-to-a-bash-function)

Comment: If you are not sure about a variable value (it could contain spaces) it is always better to enclose it between quotes i.e. `myfunc "$1"` or `myfunc "$@"`.